# d3.js Line Chart with a barchart

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a bar-chart: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579 in d3.js

I want to have a combo of the said bar chart and add a line chart for the same data.

All the line chart examples in bl.ocks are quite different.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use **c3.js** library which is a D3-based reusable chart library.

here is an example you are looking for :
[Combination Chart](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_combination.html)

You can combine 'bar','spline','line','area' etc .

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make a select box like this:

```
  <select>
    <option id="bar">bar</option>
    <option selected="selected" id="line">line</option>
  </select>
```

Make a function to make ajax and load the graph depending on the select option:

```
function getMyData() {
      d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
        x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.letter;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d.frequency;
        })]);
        //check select for the option
        if (d3.select("select").node().value == "line") {
          showLineChart(data);//make line chart
        } else {
          showBarChart(data);//make bar chart
        }
      });
    }
```

The function to make line chart:

```
function showLineChart(data) {
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

}
```

The function to make bar chart:

```
function showBarChart(data) {
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.frequency);
    })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
}
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/whoDA3K1AzXxpn8tQz2H?p=preview)

Hope this helps!